# Programs don't see fish environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, fish

If I set the `EDITOR` environment variable to `emacs` in bash, running `crontab -e` will open the crontab in emacs. When I set it in fish with

```
set -U EDITOR emacs
```

crontab opens with vim. What can I do to get crontab to open with emacs?

Answer (score 4):

In fish, if you want programs to be able to see environment variables, you have to use `set -x`. That is, to set the EDITOR variable, you should use

```
set -Ux EDITOR emacs
```

Comment: Yes, whether a variable is exported or not is distinct from the variable scope. http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#variables-export